# ¿Por qué no puedo agregar la referencia Visual CompilerServices?

Tags: c#, librería

Necesito usar esta librería para mi programa pero no aparece por ninguna parte.

La libreria es: *Visual CompilerServices*

Los errores que obtengo son:

> The name 'CallType' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) -
> C:\Users\Silvul\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Wero\MyClass.cs:34,549
>
> The name 'Versioned' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) -
> C:\Users\Silvul\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Wero\MyClass.cs:34,61
>
> The name 'CallType' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) -
> C:\Users\Silvul\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Wero\MyClass.cs:35,299
>
> The name 'Versioned' does not exist in the current context (CS0103) -
> C:\Users\Silvul\Documents\SharpDevelop Projects\Wero\MyClass.cs:35,61

Comment: Hola has añadido el espacio de nombres `System.Runtime.CompilerServices`?

Answer (score 0):

Trata de usar los espacios de nombres:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
```

Documentación: [Versioned](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.versioned?view=netframework-4.7.2) y [CallType](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.calltype?view=netframework-4.7.2)